# How to access Dropbox files when account full?

Tags: dropbox

When a free Dropbox account is full, Dropbox online tells you your account is too full and doesn't let you see the files in there to remove them. The only apparent option around this is to upgrade to a paid account.

Is there a way around this to access files and delete some or leave shared folders via the online web interface?